# How to debug the network issue in case of blocked database connections

Tags: networking, mysql, firewall

I am trying to understand if my analysis of the below information is correct. For all the 3 scenarios listed here, `port 80`, `port 3306` and `port 22` are open in the server's firewall. Also, for all the 3 scenarios I am trying to connect from outside the school's network.

**Scenario 1**

I have a `php` code which I execute as,

```
http://server.edu/file.php
```

Inside, `file.php` I have a line as,

```
mysql -h server.edu -P 3306 -u user -p password -D database
```

For scenario 1, I am able to connect to the `mysql` database.

**Scenario 2**

I have a java program using which I am trying to establish a database connection from outside the school network. I get the `connection timed out` exception.  The exception that I get is,

```
java net connectexception connection timed out connect
```

**Scenario 3**

I run my php script as `php file.php` from outside school network and I get an error in the `mysql` line.

So based on the above 3 scenarios, is it safe to believe that the school is blocking outside network connections?

I tested the `ping server.edu` and it did not work. However, I believe `ping` uses `icmp` protocol which might be not allowed in the edge firewall. Is there some other test that I can perform on this?

Comment: N° 1: Ask your school's IT staff, they might even tell you if there are allowed ways to connect from the outside. (And they might frown upon you attempting to do that without authorization.) 2. use telnet to the mysql port, that uses TCP.